# Using Python asyncore for load / stress testing a website

Tags: python, multithreading, http, asynchronous, asyncore

Hopefully someone will be able to help out with this.

Short version: I'm looking to build my own website stress tester in Python.

Why? Because I feel like it :) I'm not looking for a pre-built solution [i.e. funkload or JMeter]. It just seems like an interesting thing to do as a programming exercise. I also think that learning how to do what I want could be useful later on in other situations.

What do I want it to do? I intend to make it more complex as time goes on, but my first goal is simple: make as many requests as possible in the shortest time possible. I am shooting for 300-500 requests per second.

I've tried a number of different methods. The two most promising are:

1. Spawn threads. Lots of them. Have each thread make one request. This proved to be the fastest [easily getting up near 1 requests per second per thread -- 500 threads meant almost 500 requests per second], however it seems to be extremely intensive for the computer. The memory and computing footprint of spawning multiple hundred threads in Python is prohibitive, in my opinion. I feel like there must be a more elegant solution.
2. Use Python's asyncore library. I've been messing around with this and it seems to be really cool, but I am capping out very quickly. If I receive requests around 140 bytes, then it is capable of throwing out >1000 requests per second [awesome!], but I need it to be able to handle requests where the response is considerably larger [i.e. 100kb - 500kb]. Introducing the larger response size means that it throttles around 10-50 requests per second [if I'm lucky].

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? If I could somehow get the size of the response without actually being forced to read it in, that would be perfect. All I want to know is that I'm actually getting back the right number of bytes. What the data is doesn't matter.

Or, if that isn't an option in Python, then honestly I'd be up for trying out anything anyone has to suggest. I've played around with Twister, but didn't achieve any speeds higher than what I'd already seen with threads.

In any case -- any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you try [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) . It can accomplish this task very simply because you write code that looks synchronous and uses the python stdlib like urllib2. It will be very fast because it has low memory overhead (pay for only what you use) and it uses fast polling system calls for IO. [This code example](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/750255f7cedb/examples/concurrent_download.py) is very close to what you want. You'll want to run one gevent worker per core.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That does seem promising. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error on import after installing the library, though: http://pastebin.com/XQXM7HzD. Have you ever had any issues with anything like this?

Comment: No, libev is used in gevent 1.0 and is included with the source. The 0.13.6 version of gevent, uses libevent. The traceback in question is more likely caused by an old version of libevent used. Please install something libevent-1.4.14 and make sure you removed the old one.

Comment: or better yet, get version 1.0a2 which has all the dependencies included: http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use pycurl, the Python bindings for libcurl. It has it's own async event loop that is very fast.

There is also a simplified implementation wrapper for it that you may adapt, if you can't just use it as-is.

See the [WWW.client](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/pycopia/WWW/client.py) module of the Pycopia project (which I maintain).